# List stored functions that reference a table in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, metaprogramming

Just a quick and simple question: in PostgreSQL, how do you list the names of all stored functions/stored procedures using a table using just a SELECT statement, if possible? If a simple SELECT is insufficient, I can make do with a stored function.

My question, I think, is somewhat similar to this other question, but this other question is for SQL Server 2005:
[List of Stored Procedure from Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119679/list-of-stored-procedure-from-table)

(optional) For that matter, how do you also list the triggers and constraints that use the same table in the same manner?

Comment: [List stored functions **using a table** in PostgreSQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31166303/how-to-get-a-list-of-stored-procedures-using-a-specific-table-in-postgresql/31168357#31168357)

Answer (score 101):

```
SELECT  p.proname
FROM    pg_catalog.pg_namespace n
JOIN    pg_catalog.pg_proc p
ON      p.pronamespace = n.oid
WHERE   n.nspname = 'public';
```

Comment: As Lukáš Lalinský pointed out in his answer, PostgreSQL supports standard `information_schema.routines` -- useful for all that like standard things.

Answer (score 18):

```
SELECT  proname, prosrc
FROM    pg_catalog.pg_namespace n
JOIN    pg_catalog.pg_proc p
ON      pronamespace = n.oid
WHERE   nspname = 'public';
```

Comment: Maybe next time simply edit the post above your own rather than change a small thing

Comment: Daniel L. VanDenBosch:  He pretty much got his whole karma with the upvotes from this answer, so I don't see him doing that anytime soon.

Answer (score 16):

If you are using psql, try `\df`

From the man page:

```
Tip
To look up functions taking arguments or returning values of a specific type, use your pager's search capability to scroll through the \df output.
```

Running `\set ECHO_HIDDEN` will reveal what `\df` is running behind the scenes.

Answer (score 10):

Same as @quassnoi and @davidwhthomas, except I added the argument names in there:

```
SELECT  proname, proargnames, prosrc 
FROM    pg_catalog.pg_namespace n
JOIN    pg_catalog.pg_proc p
ON      pronamespace = n.oid
WHERE   nspname = 'public';
```

If the purpose behind listing the functions is to clean them up or iterate a new function with a changing params list, you will frequently need to drop functions:

```
DROP FUNCTION <name>(<args>);
```

By adding proargnames, I am able to construct the applicable function name for the drop.

Additionally, it's nice to see a more complete picture when evaluating the functions.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the standard `information_schema` schema to get metadata about your database (it's in the SQL standard, so it should work the same way in different database systems). In this case you want [`information_schema.routines`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/infoschema-routines.html).

Comment: Useful, but doesn't really answer the question.

Answer (score 4):

Excluding the system stuff:

```
select proname from pg_proc where proowner <> 1;
```

Comment: Why <> 1? On my Postgresql installation, system procedures have a proowner of 10, not 1.

Comment: I didn't know that. The solution is of course to change the "1" accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at my [recipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576557/). It reads functions and triggers. It is based on informations from: [Extracting META information from PostgreSQL (INFORMATION_SCHEMA)](http://www.alberton.info/postgresql_meta_info.html#.VaNFArxixB0)

Comment: Thanks, this worked. Combined with SELECT pg_catalog.pg_get_functiondef('functionName'::regproc) you can get the create statements as well.

Comment: The Extracting META... link was what worked for me I didn't see the "recipe" link till now.

Comment: Second link is dead.  :-(  Please incorporate the contents of the first link into this answer so we're not left in the dark when that one dies.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Please change the schema_name and table_name in the below query:

```
SELECT n.nspname AS schema_name
     , p.proname AS function_name
     , pg_get_function_arguments(p.oid) AS args
     , pg_get_functiondef(p.oid) AS func_def
FROM   pg_proc p
JOIN   pg_namespace n ON n.oid = p.pronamespace
AND    n.nspname = 'schema_name'
AND    p.prosrc like '%table_name%'
```

Since the table name is case sensitive, so need to define the exact table name.

Comment: Note that PostgreSQL does have the `ILIKE` keyword and the `~~*` operator, both of which can be used for case-insesitive matching.

Answer (score 0):

For retrieving the **argument types** of the functions, which are required when referencing the function in **ALTER** --  using **oldevectortypes** worked well for me.

See [How can I get a list of all functions stored in the database of a particular schema in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1347282/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-all-functions-stored-in-the-database-of-a-particular-sch/24034604#24034604)