# PostgreSQL: How to list all stored functions that access specific table

Tags: sql, postgresql

for a given table how can i find all functions that uses ANY fields from that table?
say i have student table with (studentid, studentname)

i want a list of all functions and triggers that uses studentid and studentname from student.

my question is similar to [List stored functions that reference a table in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559008/list-stored-functions-using-a-table-in-postgresql) but the code given there isn't working... `n.nspname` which is given in the condition there is related to Schema not to table.

Comment: Your table name is in the column prosrc, you have to query that column using a like or regex. This has nothing to do with the schema where the function is located.

Comment: Tables have columns, not fields... BTW, information_schema.ROUTINE_TABLE_USAGE?

Comment: what about id jarlh?

Comment: @jarlh postgresql doesn't have `information_schema.routine_table_usage`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps is not very precise, but this query should work.

```
SELECT routine_schema, routine_name 
FROM information_schema.routines 
WHERE routine_definition ~ 'student' 
AND routine_definition ~ 'studentid' 
AND routine_definition ~ 'studentname';
```

Depending on how you wrote the procedure, can you apply more precise regex expressions. In example, if you always wrote tables and columns in this form: `table.column` could you use this expression:

```
... WHERE routine_definition ~ 'student\.studentid' 
AND routine_definition ~ 'student\.studentname'
```

Comment: Since sql and plpgsql is case insensitive it's wise to use case insensitive operator `~*` to search. Also please keep in mind that function can depend on table using dynamic executed sql which may be very difficult to identify without human review.