# SQL Server : view column datatype does not change when underlying table datatype is changed?

Tags: sql-server

If I have a table `MyTable` like this:

```
Value1 decimal
```

Then I have a view `MyView`:

```
Select SUM(Value1) as SumValue1 from MyTable
```

When I look at the view's column data type in SSMS under the view's columns section it is a decimal.

Now if I modify the table to:

```
Value1 real
```

If I refresh the view's column section in SSMS the data type is still a decimal. Now if I open the view and resave it, the datatype becomes a float.

Is this how it is supposed to be? It seems that the view doesn't change until I resave it.

Comment: If you make changes to underlying tables, you need to refresh your view(s): `exec sp_refreshview 'MyView'` to bring their definition up to date again. That is indeed expected behavior. See [MSDN docs on sp_refreshview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187821.aspx).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, this is expected. Tables can be changed in ways that make the views [completely invalid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6616245/how-do-i-identify-views-with-broken-dependencies-in-sql-server). If you want to prevent this from happening, you can use the [WITH SCHEMABINDING](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956.aspx) option when creating the view. From the linked article:

*Binds the view to the schema of the underlying table or tables. When SCHEMABINDING is specified, the base table or tables cannot be modified in a way that would affect the view definition. The view definition itself must first be modified or dropped to remove dependencies on the table that is to be modified.*