# Query to get all unresolved reference tables fo all views in a database?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014

I want the get all the views along with its base tables/ objects which are missing their references as they got deleted while some operations. So, can anyone help me?

Comment: This may have what you need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6616245/how-do-i-identify-views-with-broken-dependencies-in-sql-server

Comment: Thanks for your help. Actually, I just want to find out tables/ view in all the procedures in particular database separating its object type as table/view