# Parsing stored procedures

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

Is there a way to scan a SQL Server to find all the stored procedures, read in their bodies, and determine a list of tables they use? My purpose is to perform an analysis on a large legacy database. (SQL Server 2008R2, preferably C#, but language is largely immaterial.)

Comment: Answered here perhaps?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1916489/how-to-write-a-query-for-sql-server-2008-that-returns-the-dependencies-of-an-obj

Comment: Some hints in the comments here: http://forums.asp.net/t/1225902.aspx We do something similar in our database although we have modified it to use some proprietary code so I can't post it. Our version lets us search all database on the server or only the ones we send in usinga variable. .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Leverage SQL Server's `sp_depends` system stored procedure.

1. Get a list of all your stored procedures.

```
select  specific_name   from information_schema.routines
where routine_type='PROCEDURE' and specific_name not like 'sp_%'
```

2. Use this list along with `sp_depends`, and insert its results into a table.

```
declare @t table([name] varchar(50),[type] varchar(50),
updated varchar(10),selected varchar(10),[column] varchar(50))

insert into @t exec sp_depends 'MyProc1';
insert into @t exec sp_depends 'MyProc2';
insert into @t exec sp_depends 'MyProc3';

select [name] from @t group by [name];
```

[More on `sp_depends`](https://sqlblog.org/2008/09/09/keeping-sysdepends-up-to-date-in-sql-server-2008)

Comment: This doesn't work 100% for cross-database dependencies though.

Comment: @JNK : I missed the part where the OP wanted cross database functionality.

Comment: He didn't mention it, but I wanted  to point out that `sp_depends` will not accurately report dependencies across databases.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps but you can right-click on any database in the **Object Explorer** of *SQL Management Studio* and use **Tasks --> Generate Scripts** to generate a large script containing the bodies of all stored procs (or any objects for that matter).  At that point it's just a text file you can parse for whatever you want.

Comment: I got the impression that OP wanted an automated, or semi-automated, way to do this across large databases, and this sounds a little cumbersome...

Comment: Her first sentence implies multiple databases, however she then goes on to mention a single large database - "My purpose is to perform an analysis on a large legacy database."  Since I know for a fact this method works for a single database without being very cumbersome I thought I would suggest it.

Answer (score 0):

I think this may work:

```
SELECT 
    routine_name,
    routine_definition
FROM   information_schema.routines
WHERE  routine_definition in (SELECT '%' +name+ '%' FROM   sys.tables)
       AND routine_type IN ( 'function', 'pocedure' )
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes for the first two points for sure:

```
SELECT
   pr.Name,
   mod.Definition
FROM sys.procedures pr
INNER JOIN sys.sql_modules mod ON pr.object_id = mod.object_id
```

Once you have the stored proc body (in `sql_modules`, column `definition`) you can parse it - but that'll be a bit messy at best - not sure if there's a more convenient way to do this...