# sql server get multiple levels of data

Tags: sql-server-2008

How can I achieve the following using SQL server? I am trying to get page counts in Sitefinity.

The table structure has lot of columns but below are the ones that matter

```
**Id**                  **parentid**                **title**
 ABC                        DEF                     title1
 XYZ                        DEF                     title2
 LLL                        DEF                     title3
 PPP                        ABC                     title4
 III                        ABC                     title5
 WWW                        PPP                     title6
```

A page can have subpages, and a subpage can have further subpages. In database, a subpage is represented with ID column and the parent page with parentID. How can i get count of children for each parent?

Comment: I don't have the answer right off, but you might look into CTEs, I am pretty sure that will help you build a recursion in a stored proc... Just a thought.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got the answer from the other thread : [Hierarchical Queries in SQL Server 2005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/235515/hierarchical-queries-in-sql-server-2005).

```
  WITH Parent AS
(
    SELECT
        ID,
        ParentID,
        Name AS Path
    FROM
        tblHierarchy
    WHERE
        ParentID IS NULL

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        TH.ID,
        TH.ParentID,
        CONVERT(varchar(128), Parent.Path + '/' + TH.Name) AS Path
    FROM
        tblHierarchy TH
    INNER JOIN
        Parent
    ON
        Parent.ID = TH.ParentID
)
SELECT * FROM Parent
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, something like this should get you started:

```
select id as parent,
       title as title,
       count(*) as number_children
  from table as parent
 inner join table as children
    on children.parentid = parent.id
 group by 1,2
```